# iOS displaying PDF contents as plaintext

Tags: javascript, html, ios

Our iOS users are unable to display a PDF we are calling through an AJAX request. The request looks something like this:

```
function getPdf() {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.successful) {
        window.open(PDFFormUrl, '_blank');
      }
    }
  })
}
```

On all non-iOS systems, the PDF opens up in a new tab and downloads successfully, but on iOS the function will result in the PDF file contents being displayed as plaintext instead of the actual PDF document. For some, the popup blocker also blocks the request entirely, but does not display a notification, which I believe is due to the same issue.

We determined the issue is not only with Safari, but also Chrome on iOS, so it appears to be a device-specific issue rather than a browser-specific one because Chrome on Windows or Android do not have issues displaying the document.

Comment: Chrome and other browsers on iOS are using the same engine (WebKit) as Safari, so if you are having a bug on Safari you will probably have it on other browsers.

Comment: We do see the same result on the iOS version of both browsers, but not the Mac, Windows, or Android versions.